# MSF 2013 - Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=, ClaimsCount=0

Tags: 2013, wcf, oauth

I'm developing some custom WebParts, including WCF Services to be hosted within the ISAPI directory of Sharepoint (Foundation 2013)

I'm also referencing some files from the SiteAssets (*js frameworks, imgages, css ...)

The Portal is an Sharepoint 2013 Foundation
The SiteCollection is in Legacy/Windows Authentication mode
(Changing to Claims on the test/dev system did not help)

When looking at the ULS Log I get a lot of:
**Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=, ClaimsCount=0**

Wrapped inside "Enter/Leaving monitor Scope" - with medium severity
(I didn't remove the "UserIdentityName" - it's empty in the log)

I get this message for a lot of referenced files & all of my wcf get requests.
What does this mean? This message is kind of all over the ULS log

Am I missing some config - or some Headers so set for my wcf services?
(But then why is this also occuring for plain files...)

Thnaks, Vanon